# Are certificates persistent outside of where it's created?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-revocation

For example, consider https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/ where I can get a free SSL cert. If I create a cloudflare account and get an cert but delete my cloudflare account, is the cert auto-revoked? What happens to this cert now that my cloudflare account is deleted?

Comment: If you have the private key that corresponds with the public key in the cert, and you later decide to host your domain on a different server outside of cloudflare's network, you can install the cert on the new server without a problem, unless the CA (cloudflare in this case) revokes the certificate.

Comment: Cloudflare isn't a CA, it's a reseller for other CAs like DigiCert, Let's Encrypt or Google Trust Services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudflare doesn't issue its own certificates. It's merely a reseller for certificate authorities (CAs) like DigiCert, Let's Encrypt or Google Trust Services. This means the certificates are perfectly valid outside of Cloudflare's infrastructure, and only the CAs which issued the certificates are able to revoke them.

Depending on the CA, it can be technically possible for Cloudflare to *request* certificate revocation without your consent. For example, Let's Encrypt and Google Trust Services both use the ACME protocol for automatically issuing and revoking certificates. If Cloudflare controls the ACME account, they could in principle ask the CA to revoke a particular certificate. However, it seems that [Cloudflare doesn't request certificate revocation unless they've determined hat the private key has been compromised](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/revoke-and-prevent-the-issuing-of-certificates/235478/28). Actually revoking the certificate would also be up to the CA, and each CA has a specific policy which Cloudflare has to adhere to.

Nevertheless, if you want full control over your certificates, simply use one of the free CAs like Let's Encrypt directly. There's no need for a middle man.